# Select a button on the form of a webpage

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on `upload` button which is inside a `<form>` tag.

I am using `java` with `selenium`. I  tried with `xpath locator` to click on button but unable to identify it.

Html Code:

```
    <form id="sportForm" action="/sportmetadata/saveSport" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table>
        <tr class="hidden">
          <td class="lbl-dialog">Id</font></td>
          <td>
<td class="lbl-dialog width200" >Background for Team </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-command btn-upload" value="Upload" onClick="openFileBrowser('sp_backgroundUploadId')" />
                  <input id="sp_backgroundUploadId" multiple type="file" class="no-display" name="backgroundUpload" />
                  <input id="backgroundDelesectUpload" value="Clear" type="button" onclick="clearSelection('sp_backgroundUploadId','sp_backgroundDisplayTableId');" class="btn btn-default btn-command btn-upload" />
                </td>
        </tr>
```

Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the xpath which you are trying?

Comment: //*[@id='sportForm']/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/input[1]

Comment: Please be clear in your Question. Where are you clicking? Can you share Website?

Comment: I have given the html content of the form which is being loaded after cliking on a Add button. inside that form we have a button to click. I cannot provide the website. sorry

Comment: Just try following xpath `//input[@class='btn btn-default btn-command btn-upload'][@value='Upload']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locate **Upload** button using `xpath locator`.

```
//input[@value='Upload'][@type='button']
```

**Explanation:-** Use `value` and `type` attribute of `<input>` tag.

**Suggestion:-** Instead of using `absolute xpath`, use `relative xpath`.

> OR

Locate **Upload** button using `cssSelector`

```
input[value='Upload'][type='button']
```

**Explanation:-** Use `value` and `type` attribute of `<input>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to avoid XPATH directly copied from browsers as they are not stable ones. When I copy xpath from my browser with the same HTML code I get

`//*[@id="sportForm"]/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/input[1]` which is different from what you have posted

You should build your xpath more intellegently
This should work
`//input[@type='button' and @value='Upload']`

Answer (score 0):

You can use cssSelector to identify as follows:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#sportForm > table > tr td:nth-child(3)>input"))
```